# sort array of objects by string

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject, nssortdescriptor

I have an array of managedobjects. Each has a title (name). I want to sort these NOT alphabetically, but by the one that matches a certain string the closest (the search query)

How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: how do u define "closest"?

Comment: On google if you type red bean pie, red bean pie results come up (results ordered by string)

Comment: this is not close. this is exact.

Comment: In that example yes, but say I search for read bean pies make everyone hungry.  At the top i would expect to see red bea pie if it is the closest match

Comment: so basically you want to teach the app to understand errors. Good luck — you just entered a minefield. If you want to have any chance of help, you should put some example of positive, negative and false positive hits to the question's text.

Comment: but this might be helpful: https://github.com/JanX2/NSString-DamerauLevenshtein

Comment: Haha touche... So limited by exact searches?

Comment: at least what you want to do is not simple. and core data wont be helpful at all. probably you will need a data structure in memory, that will keep the informations you want to search in memory so that you can do efficient searching on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best if you define your "closest" match function and simply assign closeness values to these objects (comparing to the search query) and sort by that instead.